# Add post order like page order

Tags: order

There is an order field when editing pages, so you can easily rearrange them, this is missing at posts, I`m thinking that there must be a simple scrip that adds this functionality to posts too.

I tried googling it, with no luck, I do not want to use a plugin if it can be done with a simple script.

thank you

Comment: can you show me at least one please?

Comment: @MaxYudin different people get different results on Google, what works for you may not work for them, so be nice

Answer (score 2):

I find it:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'posts_order' );

function posts_order() 
{
    add_post_type_support( 'post', 'page-attributes' );
}
```